# Prove that a sequence is not weakly convergent in $ \ell^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the sequence $(x^{(n)})_{n}\subset \ell^{\infty} \cong
(\ell^{1} )^{*}$ given for $x_{k}^{(n)}=1$ for $k\leq n$ and $x_{k}^{(n)}=0$ otherwise. Prove that $(x^{(n)})_{n}$ does not converge weakly to $(1,1,1,1,1,.....)$

For contradiction, I assume that the weak convergence holds, so $$f(x^{(n)}) \to f(x)$$ for every $f \in (\ell^{\infty})^{*} $. Next I can use the isometry between $(\ell^{\infty})^{*}\cong ??$ i dont know if I necessary know who is isomorphic with $(\ell^{\infty})^{*}$ and my idea here is take a sequences to use the contradiction but, how can I proceed here?

Comment: $(\ell^{\infty})^{*}$ is a huge space but one can find in it ultrafilter limits (in other words  a way to assign to any bounded $y_n$ a limit point that is compatible with algebraic operations) and for any such $\omega$ (hence for bounded $y=(y_k)$ we have that $\omega (y)$ is some limit point of $y_k$ in particular its limit if $y_k$ converges) if you fix $n$ we have that $x_k^{(n)} \to 0, k \to \infty$ so $\omega(x^{(n)})=0$ while similarly $\omega(x)=1$ since $x_k=1 \to 1, k \to \infty$

Comment: @Conrad in summary,  we can take a functional say $w \in (\ell^{\infty})^{*}$ ,  so is enough to say that as the sequence converges to $0$ then  $w(x^{(n)})$ converges to $0 $ as $k \to \infty$ and $w(x) =1$ so we have that $w(x^{(n)}) \to 0 $ and $w(x^{(n)} )\to 1$ contradicction, right?

Comment: yes but the functional need to be such that it preserves limits and as noted there are such given by ultrafilters; note that if $a_n$ is in $l^1$ one obviously has $f_a(y)= \sum a_ky_k$ is a functional on $l^{\infty}$ and $f_a(x^{(n)})=\sum_{k \le n}a_k \to f(x)=\sum a_k$ so not all functionals work

Comment: Consider the subspace $c$  of convergent sequences. Then $\varphi(x)=\lim_nx_n$ is a bounded linear functional on $c.$ By the Hahn-Banach theorem the functional $\varphi$ has an extension to a bounded linear functional  $\hat{\varphi}$ on $\ell^\infty.$  We have $\hat{\varphi}(x^{(n)})=\varphi(x^{(n)})=0$ while $\hat{\varphi}(x)=\varphi(x)=1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have a question. We know that the limit of a bounded and convergent sequence is bounded, then this is enough to say that the functional $\varphi$ is bounded or I have to use the principle of uniform bounding and from there if conclude that $\varphi$ is bounded?